# Allow SSL in valid Certificates/ Invalid hostnames in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, ssl, mongodb-atlas

I'm setting up a Cpanel server with python to connect with MongoDB atlas at regular intervals to fetch and process data.  I'm always getting an Error 101: Connection refused when reading data. So, decided to use --tlsAllowInvalidCertificates and --sslAllowInvalidHostnames option.

But, where do I need to do it.

I tried by installing Mongodb Enterprise server on my machine and connected to the host cluster. In the past, I tried these commands directly but it throws an error as command not defined.

--tlsAllowInvalidCertificates